# jQuery delay and fadeOut sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with delay() and hide() on multiple elements.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<div id="one">
<p id="label1_one">text</p>
<p id="label2_one">text</p>
</div>

<div id="two">
<p id="label1_two">text</p>
<p id="label2_two">text</p>
</div>

<div id="three">
<p id="label1_three">text</p>
<p id="label2_three">text</p>
</div>
```

and script

```
function toogle(){
if (1){
$("#one").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#label1_two").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_two").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label1_three").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_three").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
}
if (2){
$("#two").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#label1_one").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_one").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label1_three").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_three").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
}
if (3){
$("#three").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#label1_one").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_one").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label1_two").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
$("#label2_two").css("display", "inline-block").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
}
}
```

Each time some of elements stays visible on page.
Is there some known problem with this.

Or someone can point me to some other solution.

```
Code is example from real situation. :)
```

Thanks in advance,
Vedran

Comment: what does `if (1)` mean? provide a non-working example in jsfiddle, so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: What is the problem? I mean, besides `if (1)`, `if (2)` and `if (3)` being useless because they will always execute.

Comment: Are you trying to do them all at the same time, because that's almost what you are doing? Should I assume you want a delay between each id?

Comment: I would be a lot better, if you can show your actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(1)
```

means it will always visit your if-statements

If you're referring to the `div` id, in your jQuery, you need to change it to something like this:

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    //do something.
});
```

Comment: @Sparky Oh I'm so sorry. Stupid mistake by me. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .stop method (http://api.jquery.com/stop/) , if the error occurs when you try to animate an already animating object calling stop will clear all animations before start

```
$("#label1_one").css("display", "inline-block").stop(true, true).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: "text-speak" is not welcome at SO.  Please correct your spelling.  Thank-you.